# How to generate POM for fat JAR (shadow) without dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, shadowjar

I'm building a module with `gradle sub-app:build` and it creates the fat JAR in `./dist` folder with a `pom.xml`. The POM contains all the dependencies even though they are all included in the JAR. I want my `pom.xml`'s `<dependencies>` part to be empty since I do not need to download those things when running the JAR.

It's a Spring Boot application. I'm using shadow JAR for creating the fat JAR. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that the `pom.xml` inside the JAR comes into play when running the JAR? Usually the POM's there for build time, not for runtime.

Comment: Correct. @OP what's the actual error when you run the jar?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting! @GeroldBroser is correct I don't need anything from the POM to run the jar my bad.